# React tree view: entry addition via drag, node deletion via context menu and sorting

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, treeview, draggable, droppable

I am working on a project that requires a tree-view component with following features,

- New entry will be added if a draggable component of specific type is dropped on any existing node.
- Nodes are sortable
- Nodes can be deleted using a context menu

So far [rc-tree](https://github.com/react-component/tree) is the closest match I found. But it doesn't seem to have the capability to add node via external component drop. When attempting to drop a simple droppable component like this,

```
<p className="rat" style={{"backgroundColor": "#ddd"}} draggable>Draggable</p>
```

it's throwing `error` when dragged over a node:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined.

How can I make an external draggable component compatible? Or, is there a better way or at least a different library?

Comment: Did you find a workaround / another lib? I face the same issue